# Material Desing Lite no carga en Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5, material-design-lite

Excelente día a todos,
Estoy usando Angular 5 y estoy cargando Material Desing Lite a travez de su CDN dento del index.html de mi poryecto Angular, pero cuando ingreso a la sección donde estoy cargado los elementos de Material Desing Lite no se cargar conrrectamente tengo que recargar la página para que me funcionen correctamente, cabe mencionar que ya he usado el JS como asincrono pero de igual manera no cargan correctamente

De esta manera estoy agregando mis elemetos (como dice en la documentación)

```
<form action="">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
       <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="tb-nombre">
       <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="tb-nombre">Nombre Completo</label>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto, les decio buen día a todos :)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta, lamento mucho la molesti apero se supne que eso se debe meter al TS (main.ts) de mi aplicación por enede debe quedar algo asi

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.log(err));

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).

run(function($rootScope, xxxx, xxx){
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event, next) {
    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
});
});
```